# The waiting general

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> "I am waiting
> waiting for you
> for you to come...
>
> Here I stand
> facing their lines,
> the scores of them
> fill my vision.
>
> My troops too few,
> I can't attack,
> but you can.
>
> Then attack,
> strike them down,
> and when you're finished,
> tell me what you've done."

Hint 1:

> Don't worry about friendly fire
>  for if you do it well and report,
>  I can easily restore.

Hint 2:

> I'm still too young...
>  ...to see your success directly.
>  But I can still infer,
>  by looking at their numbers.
>  If you succeed,
>  they decrease a little.

Hint 3:

> Usual puzzle-solving strategies don't work here. Here, you push a button.

Comment: Could you be bothered to comment? I think prog_SAHIL has it, your hint 1 fits, too. looks solved to me. Please give us an update.

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick Answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

I am

> Bowling

Explanation:

I am waiting,
waiting for you,
for you to come...

> You wait for the bowling ball to come to you

Here I stand,
facing their lines,
the scores of them,
fill my vision.

> In bowling arenas, the scoreboards are usually in front on pins.

My troops too few,
I can't attack,
but you can.

> The troops are the bowling balls (too few as you only have 2 per set). You as a person cannot attack the pins but the ball can

Then attack,
strike them down,
and when you're finished,
tell me what you've done.

> We knock/strike them down with our bowling bowl. And when its done it tells us our score

Comment: Good one. Fits nicely to having to tell what you've done after the strike.

Comment: Sorry, the answer is incorrect. You can see, the ball itself doesn't tell us our score.

Comment: @user_194421 can you hint whether this answer is at least in the right ballpark, literally? - If so, I would rephrase the individual explanations within the same theme so that they'd seem more fitting to me. - OK, seems obsolete with your second hint. Nevermind.

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick It's far away

Answer (score 1):

This seems quite fitting to how

> One of the Flag pieces in the Board Game Stratego

might describe the situation.

Since

> It's the only piece not allowed to move and hence can't attack.
>
> You always feel like too few troops (if both sides had enough troops, nobody would ever win)
>
> Players don't see the value of the opposite piece until after an attack. So after a strike, the players tell each other what their pieces are.

Not a perfect hit, but worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> A program with bugs, lot of bugs

**Explanations**
I am waiting
waiting for you
for you to come...

> As you are bugged you are waiting for me the user to debug you

Here I stand
facing their lines,
the scores of them
fill my vision.

> You're seeing bugs in the debug log and it is all you see

My troops too few,
I can't attack,
but you can.

> As a program, you don't have the tools to degug yourself alone

Then attack,
strike them down,
and when you're finished,
tell me what you've done.

> You're asking me to destroy bugs and to report by saving the file again.

Don't worry about friendly fire
for if you do it well and report,
I can easily restore.

> If I make a mistake, like deleting a friendly line, I can still ask you to restore the older file

I'm still too young...
...to see your success directly.
But I can still infer,
by looking at their numbers.
If you succeed,
they decrease a little.

> As the program improve, you're to be replace by another version and graduatly you will change and maybe never see my entire success. Finally you can told me how many bugs are still in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm new in this puzzling stack exchange, so please tell me if there's something wrong with my answering format. Now to the answer

**I am**

> White pool ball

**The reason are**

> In snooker, there are 15 red ball which can be said as "scores". The colored ball is the troops which is only a few. The only ball that can "attack" is only the cue ball hence the line "but you can". The last part if self explanatory if it's pool (strike the ball down and report the result)

**Additional reason**

> First hint said, it's okay to friendly fire since after finish the game the ball will be returned to the position again. The second hint said that their number will decrease if you succeed which refer to the pool balls decrease after you put the balls in the pocket

Answer (score 1):

This was posted when

> I had below 1000 reputation, so I couldn't see vote count breakdowns. (this explains Hint 2)

And the answer is

> Pressing the downvote button

Explanation:

> The "general" thing is just a narration.

> Hint 1:
>  Don't worry about friendly fire
>  for if you do it well and report,
>  I can easily restore.

> Reputation is more easily gained than lost

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> An **arcade game**? More precisely if needed, **Space Invaders**?

Because

> The game needs you to defeat lines after lines of enemies, and offers you a score screen at the end

Answer (score 0):

If my theory is correct, you are

> General Chicanery, a tag from [a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53490/contact), and you're inviting us to play *Contact* - a game in which a word is attacked and defended.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it should be winning cross ribbon at race ending

```
"I am waiting
waiting for you
for you to come...
```

> Sports person run for win and that race winning ribbon wait for them

```
Here I stand
facing their lines,
the scores of them
fill my vision.
```

> It stand at place and sports person touch it by torso and it will tell scores either person is first winner or not.

```
My troops too few,
I can't attack,
but you can.
```

> Ribbon can not attack obviously, Person can attack it to win

```
Then attack,
strike them down,
and when you're finished,
tell me what you've done."
```

> After runner finished with run they touch it and fall down

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> Chess pieces

I am waiting waiting for you for you to come...

Here I stand facing their lines, the scores of them fill my vision.

> Your chess pieces face the opponent's pieces. A score is 20, or roughly 20, and each player has 16 game pieces.

My troops too few, I can't attack, but you can.

> You move the chess pieces, they can't attack on their own.

Then attack, strike them down, and when you're finished, tell me what you've done.

> Declaring your move after you have made it in chess.

Don't worry about friendly fire for if you do it well and report, I can easily restore.

> When a pawn reached the opponent's side, you promote it / restore it to a piece previously taken.

I'm still too young...to see your success directly. But I can still infer, by looking at their numbers. If you succeed, they decrease a little.

> Every time you succeed by taking an opponent's piece, the amount of pieces they have decrease.

Comment: That dors not fit well the number idea. And explanation for score is weak. Hard riddle